# Submenu sobreposto por outros componentes

Tags: css

Tenho o seguinte código que exibe um menu-submenu.

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-xs" style="overflow: visible !important; ">
     <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-white dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="true" style=" border-color: #ccc; overflow: visible !important;">
          <i class="ace-icon fa fa-angle-down icon-on-right"></i>
     </button>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="overflow: visible !important;">
        <li class="dropdown-submenu" style="overflow: visible !important;">
            <a href="#">AAA</a>
        </li>                        
     </ul>
</div>
```

Porém dentro de uma datatable, o submenu é sobreposto por outros componentes.

Percebi que exibe corretamente removendo o ui-datatable que o prime gera, mas claro o layout fica comprometido.

```
<div id="list" class="ui-datatable ui-widget">
```

Tentei inserir o overflow mas nada mudou.

Alguém teria alguma ideia do que poderia estar ocasionando isso ?

Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o seu problema seja por uma falha na definição do 'z-index' que é o responsável por criar planos, ou níveis de camadas.

Por exemplo, se você definir a classe com `z-index:1` e uma outra classe com `z-index:10`, a div com o index 10 irá ficar por cima da outra.

Então para resolver o seu problema, basta definir um `z-index` para o seu dropdown.

```
.dropdown-menu {
    position:relative;
    z-index:99;
}
```

Atenção: para o z-index funcionar, você deve ter a propriedade de position definida também, então verifique se o seu css já possui essa propriedade. Se não possuir, recomendo usar o position relative, que não terá influência direta no seu layout.

Outra observação a ser feita é com o uso da propriedade z-index. Você deve tomar muito cuidado. Muitas pessoas começam a definir a partir de 999 e depois começam a aumentar nesse ritmo, acabando com um código confuso.

Desconheço um guia que seja considerado como ideal ou correto, mas no meu fluxo de trabalho eu normalmente organizo por importância de elemento e começo com definições em dezenas. Exemplo:

Menu é de prioridade máxima, utilizando a dezena 90, então eu posso definir o menu com 90, uma logo com 91 e o dropdown com 92.

Já o meu header é de prioridade secundária, então defino com dezena 80, e assim por diante.